# Connect app to RethinkDB server on AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, web, rethinkdb

I am attempting to connect my app, which is currently on localhost, to a rethinkdb server on AWS. I used the rethinkdb AMI to get the server configured and up and running. However, I keep getting a failed to connect message. I am using rethinkdbdash to attempt the connection (https://github.com/neumino/rethinkdbdash). The following is my connection code and no passsword on the db for right now. Anyone know how to connect to it:

```
let r = rethinkdbdash({
   db: 'test', 
   user: 'rethinkdb', 
   servers: [{host: 'my.aws.ip.addr', port: '28015'}]
});
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?  You may need to go into AWS and open the port.

Answer (score 1):

Made a mistake in the connection syntax... the actual syntax should have been:

```
let r = rethinkdbdash(
{
    host: 'ip.addr.here',
    db: 'test',
});
```